# css display webkit box in table

Tags: html, css

In below Image td A and td B has "lined" and "thick" class. When I apply lines and thickes to BCD the format in table becomes messed-up. Why?

All images and code are below.

[image: Image1]

When I add "lined" and "thick" class in td C. It display like this:

[image: Image2]

When I add "lined" and "thick" class in td D. It will display like this:

[image: Image3].

Forgive for my poor English. I'm Taiwanese.

My code is in image and script-form for Css and HTML here below:

[image: CssImage].

[image: HtmlCode]

```css
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans);

.button-Blue {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #258cd1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    text-decoration: none
}
    .button-Blue:hover {
        color: white;
        background-color: #49abed;
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #439cd8;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        text-decoration: none
    }
    .button-Blue:active {
        color: white;
        background-color: #49abed;
        transform: translateY(4px);
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #439cd8;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
        text-decoration: none
    }
.button-Yellow {
    background-color: #edeb5e;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #d6d34f;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none
}
    .button-Yellow:hover {
        color: black;
        background-color: #f4f273;
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #e0df64;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        text-decoration: none
    }

    .button-Yellow:active {
        color: black;
        background-color: #f4f273;
        transform: translateY(4px);
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #e0df64;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
        text-decoration: none
    }
.tableShadow {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px #999;
}

.button-Green {
    background-color: #51d166;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #4dc160;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none
}

    .button-Green:hover {
        color: black;
        background-color: #62db76;
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #5ace6d;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        text-decoration: none
    }

    .button-Green:active {
        color: black;
        background-color: #62db76;
        transform: translateY(4px);
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #5ace6d;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
        text-decoration: none
    }

.button-Orange {
    background-color: #e0a32a;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #cc9324;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none
}

    .button-Orange:hover {
        color: black;
        background-color: #edb038;
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #db9e29;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        text-decoration: none
    }

    .button-Orange:active {
        color: black;
        background-color: #edb038;
        transform: translateY(4px);
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #db9e29;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
        text-decoration: none
    }


.button-White {
    background-color: #dee2e2;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #d6dbdb;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none
}

    .button-White:hover {
        color: black;
        background-color: #eaeded;
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #dee0e0;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        text-decoration: none
    }

    .button-White:active {
        color: black;
        background-color: #eaeded;
        transform: translateY(4px);
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #dee0e0;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
        text-decoration: none
    }

.button-White {
    background-color: #dee2e2;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #d6dbdb;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none
}

    .button-White:hover {
        color: black;
        background-color: #eaeded;
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #dee0e0;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        text-decoration: none
    }

    .button-White:active {
        color: black;
        background-color: #eaeded;
        transform: translateY(4px);
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #dee0e0;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
        text-decoration: none
    }

.button-Purple {
    background-color: #aa6ae2;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #985dcc;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none
}

    .button-Purple:hover {
        color: black;
        background-color: #ba7bf2;
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #ac70e0;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        text-decoration: none
    }

    .button-Purple:active {
        color: black;
        background-color: #ba7bf2;
        transform: translateY(4px);
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px 0px #ac70e0;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
        text-decoration: none
    }


.button-border-Blue {
    cursor: pointer;
    
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 22px;
    transition: .3s;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    -moz-transition: .3s;
    -o-transition: .3s;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #55acee;
    border: 2px #55acee solid;
    text-align:center;
}


    .button-border-Blue:hover {
        background-color: #55acee;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none
    }

.button-border-Red {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 22px;
    transition: .3s;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    -moz-transition: .3s;
    -o-transition: .3s;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #e74c3c;
    border: 2px #e74c3c solid;
    text-align: center;
}


    .button-border-Red:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #e74c3c;
        text-decoration: none
    }


.lined.thick {
    border: solid 4px #41403E;
    -ms-flex-item-align: center;
    align-self: center;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    

    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    color: #41403E;
    font-size: 2rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 20px 38px 34px -26px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 20px 38px 34px -26px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 255px 15px 225px 15px/15px 225px 15px 255px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication8.Models.Quest>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
 table {
        
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 /* Zebra striping */
 tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eee;
 }

 th {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
        padding:6px;
 }

 td, th {
 
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .remark {
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-width: 100px;
  
 }
    .scrollDiv{
        overflow:scroll;
        max-height:300px;
    }
 @@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {

  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
   display: block;
    
  }

   /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
   thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
   }

  tr {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  .remark {
   max-width: 100%;
  }
  td {
   /* Behave  like a "row" */
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
   position: relative;
   padding-left: 30%;
      
  }
   
   td:before {
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    
   }

   /*
 Label the data
 */
   td:nth-of-type(1):before {
    content: "試卷名稱";
    font-weight: bold;
   }

   td:nth-of-type(2):before {
    content: "操作";
    font-weight: bold;
   }

   td:nth-of-type(3):before {
    content: "題目數量";
    font-weight: bold;
    
   }

   td:nth-of-type(4):before {
    content: "備註";
    font-weight: bold;
    
   }

   td:nth-of-type(5):before {
    content: "狀態";
    font-weight: bold;
   }

   
 }

    .coordinate {
        width: 64px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 5px;
        padding: 2px;
        white-space: pre-line
    }

    .coordinate2{
        margin-bottom:0px;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/MyCss/style.css"/>
 
<div class="">
 <p>
  <a style="font-size:20px;text-decoration:none;color:white" class="button-Blue" href="/Quests/Create?ClassId=@ViewBag.ClassId">新增試卷</a><!--test-->
 </p>
    
 @if (ViewBag.authError != null)
 {
  <h2 style="color:darkred">權限不足無法進入</h2>
 }

    <div class="scrollDiv">
        <table class="tableShadow">
            <thead><tr><th>試卷名稱</th><th>操作</th><th>題目數量</th><th>備註</th><th>狀態</th></tr></thead>

            @foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.clas.id == ViewBag.ClassId && x.status.Equals("未作答")))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:inherit" class="lined thick">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:25%">
                        @Html.ActionLink("試卷\n列表", "Edit", new { id = item.id },new { @class = "button-Green coordinate" }) 
                        @Html.ActionLink("試卷\n內容", "Details", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "button-Orange coordinate" }) 
                        @Html.ActionLink("題目\n列表", "QuestionsList", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "button-Purple coordinate" })

                        @Html.ActionLink("刪除\n試卷", "Delete", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "button-White coordinate" })

                    </td>
                    <td class="lined thick" style="width:inherit">
                        @item.questions.Count()
                    </td>
                    <td class="lined thick" >
                        
                        @if (item.remark == null)
                        {
                            @:nothing
               }
                        else
                        {
                            @item.remark
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td class="lined thick">
                        @item.status
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </div>
    <p>
        <h2 class="lined thick"><b>已作答試卷</b></h2>
    </p>
    <div class="scrollDiv">
        <table>
            <thead><tr><th>試卷名稱</th><th>操作</th><th>題目數量</th><th>備註</th><th>狀態</th></tr></thead>

            @foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.clas.id == ViewBag.ClassId && x.status.Equals("已作答")))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:40%" class="lined thick">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:25%">
                        @Html.ActionLink("編輯試卷", "Edit", new { id = item.id }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("試卷內容", "Details", new { id = item.id }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("題目列表", "QuestionsList", new { id = item.id })

                        |@Html.ActionLink("刪除試卷", "Delete", new { id = item.id })

                    </td>
                    <td class="lined thick">
                        @item.questions.Count()
                    </td>
                    <td class="remark lined thick" style="width:20%">
                        @if (item.remark == null)
                        {
                            @:nothing
   }
                        else
                        {
                            @item.remark
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td class="lined thick">
                        @item.status
                    </td>
                </tr>}

        </table>
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("返回", "ClassIndex", new { id = ViewBag.CourseId })
        </div>
    </div>
@section Scripts {
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  function myFunction() {
   var x = $(window).width(); 
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
 </script>
}
```

[Image that I want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqswj.jpg)
The result that I want is I want this two td  display like left td.
But when I add the "lined" and "thick" class to this two td. The table will display like [Image2],[Image3]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are probably setting the css class to `tr` instead of `td`. Please correct and it should resolve the error.

Please provide the code and I can check it

Comment: I update the image of HTML. I'm sure that I  set css class to td .

Comment: Instead of an image, please paste the HTML and CSS code here. Do not worry about language specific format.

Comment: The result is correct. You are having a loop so the class will be applied to all of the rows in that table. What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry I paste the wrong html file code. I have changed the HTML that have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add on a div inside

Like this:

```html
<td style="width:40%">
   <div class="lined thick">
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
   </div>
</td>
```

Because the webkit is overwriting the display for table, while in table, display should be table cell. So try not to overwrite the table cell